# Message Consumer Issue

Tags: message-queue, orocommerce

I am using Orocommerce 4.0 on my Win10 system and i did some tasks in my custom bundle. It is containin adding products into db programmaticaly. If i want to see the products that I've created and the prices of those products in the Listing Page (Products navigation-root) message consumer should work in the background. Message consumer is working but not doing the inserting products and recalculating prices that is why I still cannot see them in frontend All Products navigation the Listing Page. There is no problem with the Main page cause i see them in there and same with the admin ui but something wrong with the message consumer or prices or currency that i can't see them in the All Products page (navigation-root/products). So anybody can tell what s wrong or what can i do about this I will be so thankful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the website reindex and price recalculation manually from the command line and then wait back the message consumer to process it.

For more information, see the documentation.

- https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/architecture/tech-stack/search-index/#triggering-reindexation
- https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/pricing/optimize-index-and-price-calculation/#price-recalculation

Also, you should notice that the latest OroCommerce versions are not fully compatible with Windows as a development environment, because it relies on a PHP extension that is not available on Windows. So you can have some unexpected issues there.

I recommend a switch to Linux or Mac for development or use WSL or Docker if you have any experience with them.

Comment: Thank you Andrey i did trigger the website reindex and also price recalculation manually too but there is no change. You recommended Linux or Mac and I am using Centos via VirtualBox I tried there too but no change again. Is there anything i can do apart from these. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Then it looks like new products data are not valid or there is something missing. It's hard to say without debugging. Are these new entities are missing only on a storefront or you also can't see them in the back-office?

Comment: I think there is no problem with new entities cause I can see them on the Main page (index.php) and Admin UI also.I can update new products from Admin UI. In addition, I can see the details of the new products on the frontend with product' url slug or with product id and the info of the product is true if i have to mention..If you can think of another idea, this is very valuable for me. Thank you so so much again.

Comment: If you have different data on a product view and product listing pages - the issue definitely in a search index. So reindex should fix it. Make sure you run the console command and the website in the same environment. For example, if you access the website using index.php, then all the commands should be run with `--env=prod` option.

Comment: Yeah i know about the environment i am just going to reindex again. Thank you again.

Comment: Andrey sorry for bothering again but I just realized a debug from message consumer the message like this "consumer.DEBUG : Make sure the queue "oro.default" exists on a broker side." and the other one like this " consumer.DEBUG: Switch to a queue oro.default". Can these messages be the reasons for not seeing the products on Listing page?

Comment: No, DEBUG level messages are just informative, if there are no ERROR or CRITICAL level messages - it's not related.